# Google Maps Directions API response duration time format - Python

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps, datetime, google-directions-api

I wrote the Directions API and the response is what I would expect it to be.

Here's the sample response from documentation:

```
"duration": {
    "value": 74384,
    "text": "20 hours 40 mins"
  },
  "distance": {
    "value": 2137146,
    "text": "1,328 mi"
  },
```

I wanted to check with the community if there is a way for the API to return a formatted text for duration.

*"20 hours 40 mins"* is formatted as string, however, I'd like to be able to perform operations with duration, so time format would be ideal. I am thinking it would be good practice to have the response be formatted versus transforming the pandas dataframe. That's the alternative I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the "value" variable of "duration" which is in seconds to timedelta()

Example :

```
import datetime as dt
dt.timedelta(seconds = value)
```

Hope this helps!